# provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating specified server / instance While running my web application MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, database-connection

I'm building a website using `MVC5` `C#` and `MSSQL` it was working like sharm, after a moment when i launch debug i got this error below :
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOxlp.png)

I can access to server database via sql server management studio

I dont know how to resolve this probleme.

Comment: Can you show us your code and include the error in the question (not as a screenshot)

Comment: are you accessing from the same machine when using sql management studio - whats your connection string?

Comment: Yes, same machine.        <add name="NAMEENTITES" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NAMEEntities.csdl|res://*/NAMEEntities.ssdl|res://*/NAMEEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[IP ADRESS];initial catalog=[Database];persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=[PASSWORD];multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

Comment: Hintham : Its not deppending on code, just on load the root, exactly after debugging and VS doent catch any exception